# Java Double variable refuses to go negative after subtraction

Tags: java, double

```
double interest_pos = 1.0003, interest_neg = -0.002;
            double balance = CustomersList.getItem(i).get_balance();
            boolean transacted = false;
            for ( int mth = 1; mth <= 31; mth++ )
            {   
                System.out.println(balance);
                for ( int j = 1; j <= numTrans; j++ )
                {           
                    if ( CustomersList.getItem(i).get_accountid() == TransList.getItem(j).get_accountid() )
                    {   
                        String tempdate = TransList.getItem(j).get_date();
                        date = tempdate.split(delimiter);
                        if ( TransList.getItem(j).get_type().equals("credit") && Integer.parseInt(date[0]) == mth && !transacted )
                        {
                            balance += TransList.getItem(j).get_amount();
                            transacted = true;
                            if ( balance >= 0 ) balance *= interest_pos;
                            else balance *= interest_neg;
                        }
                        else if ( TransList.getItem(j).get_type().equals("credit") && Integer.parseInt(date[0]) == mth && transacted )
                        {
                            balance += TransList.getItem(j).get_amount();
                        }
                        else if ( TransList.getItem(j).get_type().equals("debit") && Integer.parseInt(date[0]) == mth && transacted )
                        {
                            System.out.println( "Deducted " + TransList.getItem(j).get_amount());
                            balance -= TransList.getItem(j).get_amount();
                        }
                        else if ( TransList.getItem(j).get_type().equals("debit") && Integer.parseInt(date[0]) == mth && !transacted )
                        {       
                            balance -= TransList.getItem(j).get_amount();
                            transacted = true;
                            if ( balance >= 0 ) balance *= interest_pos;
                            else balance *= interest_neg;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ( balance >= 0 ) balance *= interest_pos;
                            else balance *= interest_neg;
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println ("Day " + mth + " Balance " + balance );
                transacted = false;
```

Above is part of my code. The rest of my code reads in data from a text file, and everything works well until the part where the double value is supposed to be subtracted by 500.0.

Day 22 Balance 225.86301881168654

Day 23 Balance 0.5478672869645392

After Day 22, it's supposed to be -275.54...... but instead it shows what it's showing now. This is the last component of my assignment and I'm stuck here for hours looking for solutions! Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT: I've put in more of my code, is it an issue with how java deals with mathematical operations in a binary form that when *225.86301881168654 - 500.0* it becomes the weird result i get?

Comment: Try posting complete code - You're using `balance` uninitialized in the posted snippet.

Comment: please post a minimal complete program that exhibits the bug. it not only helps us to help you, but often in the process of doing so you will find the bug yourself.

Comment: What's the value of interest_neg?

Comment: it does not go into negative values for interest_neg to take effect.

Comment: @Erik are you feel better with this code?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code which produces this error which we could run? You are using double without any rounding, but I don't believe you could get a round error this large.

Comment: We still can't see where the 500.0 is supposed to come from. Look, we know that 225-500 is way below -200, so if it is not, then either your floating point unit is broken or you did not subtract 500. I bet the latter is the case.

Comment: The 500.0 comes from TransList.getItem(j).get_amount();, which is a LinkedList of objects. I've tried just "System.out.println(balance - 500.0)" at day 22 and the same result materialises.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey It starts off with a value of 566.00, multiplied by 0.003% each day, with credit and debit transactions happening over the course of the month.

Comment: I just noted that whenever you multiply with interest_neg (-0.002) then a very small number will be the result. The unexpected result IS a small number (for a balance sheet anyway). This should give you an idea where to look for. The best thing would be to trace any operation you perform to the balance.

Comment: If you really subtract 500 and get 0.54, then the only possiblilty left is that the balance before was 500.54. Do yourself a favor and log EVERY transaction if logic does not convince you.

Comment: @ingo, a small number and a negative will become a positive. ;) I would like to get a loan at this Bank. ;)

Comment: @Ingo Jesus you are right with the interest_neg. I neglected to add the 1. Thank you so much. I've a lab test soon so I'm a little panicky, apologies for the stupidity and carelessness and thank you for the time!

Comment: And, indeed, you subtract 500 and then you multiply by -0.002, which gives a positive number on -250. Lets approximate 250*2 /1000 upps, its around 0.5!!!!

Comment: @Peter, the error is or was in the last else if block. Lets assume balance is approx. 250. He subtracts 500, gives -250 and then he multiplies this by -0.002. Result is 0.5

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what the exact issue is here, but use [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) (instead of `double`) when working with money.

Comment: +1  "Using floating point for dollars-and-cents calculations is a recipe for disaster. Floating point numbers are best reserved for values such as measurements, whose values are fundamentally inexact to begin with." http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0114/

Comment: @Jason - get rid of all `double` variables and replace them with `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you step through your code using a debugger and you would see how your values are actually changing.

Your negative interest is interest_neg = -0.002. which you multiply by your amount.

Say you have the following situation

```
double balance = -100;
if ( balance >= 0 ) balance *= interest_pos;
else balance *= interest_neg; // balance = -100 * -0.002 = +0.2
```

A negative interest doesn't make any sense of this value as you can see. If I had a million dollar debt, the next month I would have $200.  The more in debt I am the more money I will have next month.

So whenever you have a negative balance you are making it positive again.  Perhaps your negative interest should be 1.002, similar to your positive interest.

```
else balance *= interest_neg; // balance = -100 * 1.002 = -100.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what happen when we don't see full of your code but this changes should help to you:

```
double balance;
System.out.println(balance);
balance -= TransList.getItem(j).get_amount();
System.out.println(balance);
transacted = true;
if ( balance >= 0 ) balance *= interest_pos;
else balance *= interest_neg;
System.out.println(balance);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran myself pretty ragged over this whole "Negative Double" variable issue, as the sum amount was definitely negative.  Performing IF statements that if the 2nd variable was > the 1st variable it would flip the variables and then multiply by -1.  That didn't work though....  The doubles actually calculate perfectly...I had a BOOLEAN statement lower in the code that was only looking for positive amounts.  It saved me from having to rewrite dozens of variables.  I hope this helps someone.